# pyramid string pattern in java using for loop

Tags: java

```
    A
   ABA
  ABCBA
 ABCDCBA
```

i am trying to make this pattern in  java but i am not able to figure out .
i have tried this .i am trying to make this pattern in  java but i am not able to figure out .
i have tried this . i am trying to make this pattern in  java but i am not able to figure out .
i have tried this .

```
package rem;
public class test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(char i='A';i<='E';i++)
        {
            for(char k='E';k>=i;k--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(char j='A';j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            for(char j=i;j>'A';j--)
            {
                System.out.print(j);

            }

            System.out.println("");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple java program of pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373738/simple-java-program-of-pyramid)

Comment: @saurabh are you asking to convert this code to c?

Comment: @kevinEsche what did you mean by "This does not fit his delivered output "

Comment: @FastSnail no i just want it simple without downcating

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain creating a pyramid in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905617/explain-creating-a-pyramid-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This way it's work.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(char i='A';i<='E';i++)
        {
            for(char k='E';k>=i;k--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(char j='A';j<=i-1;j++) // changed
            {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            for (char j = i; j >= 'A'; j--) { // changed
                System.out.print(j);

            }

            System.out.println("");

        }
    }
```